# Finding dot product in r

Tags: r, matrix, transpose, dot-product

I am trying to find the dot product of two matrices in R. In the q matrix, which must be transposed, I have three different q values that I randomly generated earlier, and in the z matrix three randomly generated z values that serve as coordinates of a random point i.  I have:

```
    z0= NULL
    for (i in 1:100){
        z0[i]= 1
    }
    z1= runif(100, min=0, max= 20)
    z2= runif(100, min=0, max=20)
    q0= runif(1, 0, 1)
    q1= runif(1, 0, 1)
    q2= runif(1, 0, 1)
    i= runif(1, 1, 101)
    i= ceiling(i-1)
    q= matrix(c(q0,q1,q2), ncol=3)
    z= matrix(c(z0[i],z1[i],z2[i]), ncol=3)
    s[i]= t(q)*z
```

However, when I try to calculate s[i], I get `Error in t(q) * z : non-conformable arrays`. I am not sure why this would be as I they seem to both have the same length.

This is my first time using R so I am not really sure what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to show a reproducible example `q= matrix(c(q0,q1,q2), ncol=3)
Error in matrix(c(q0, q1, q2), ncol = 3) : object 'q0' not found`

Comment: Dot product is `%*%`.

Comment: @akrun, I have made it reproducible, sorry for not doing that before.

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell  Have you tried Pascal's suggestion

Comment: @Pascal, I changed it to %*% but not get the error: Warning message:
In s[i] = t(q) %*% z :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell  Based on the example, it worked.

Comment: @akrun do you mean my example in the question changed to use %*%? With that I get the error that I mentioned in my last comment to Pascal

Comment: @Khashaa I get the same error when I use crossprod

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell  It is better to set a seed for making it reproducible. i.e. `set.seed(1)` before the  `runif`. This is what I get `crossprod(q, z)
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.7622588 10.68985 14.67339
[2,] 0.8413184 11.79857 16.19527
[3,] 0.8964904 12.57230 17.25733`

Comment: Where did you define `s`?

Comment: @akrun are you using exactly what I wrote just with crossprod(q,z?). Are you using the R console? If so, we are doing the same things so I'm not sure why it is not working for me...

Comment: @Khashaa I should have included s= NULL , sorry

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell Set some seed. `set.seed(1); z1= runif(100, min=0, max= 20);....crossprod(q,z)`

Comment: It worked!! Thanks. But now how do I get the dot product from this?

Comment: @akrun forgot to tag you

Comment: @Khashaa I got the same error "rror in v %*% w : non-conformable arguments". crossprod(v, w) helped. Thanks.

Comment: a,b are both matrix:  then a %*% b

Answer (score 15):

Without using matrices or any special libraries:

The dot product of two vectors can be calulated by multiplying them element-wise with `*` then summing the result.

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)

sum(a*b)
```

Comment: A special case that only works for vectors: The OP asked for matrices.

Answer (score 6):

As Pascal says, dot product in R is %*%.  I am able to use this successfully on your sample data:

```
> z0= NULL
> for (i in 1:100){
+     z0[i]= 1
+ }
> z1= runif(100, min=0, max= 20)
> z2= runif(100, min=0, max=20)
> q0= runif(1, 0, 1)
> q1= runif(1, 0, 1)
> q2= runif(1, 0, 1)
> i= runif(1, 1, 101)
> i= ceiling(i-1)
> q= matrix(c(q0,q1,q2), ncol=3)
> z= matrix(c(z0[i],z1[i],z2[i]), ncol=3)
> t(q)%*%z
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.3597998 3.227388 2.960053
[2,] 0.3544622 3.179510 2.916141
[3,] 0.3550781 3.185035 2.921208
> z%*%t(q)
         [,1]
[1,] 4.340265
```

Answer (score 6):

Sample Answer:

```
library(geometry)
dot(A,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like others have tackled your issue, I'll just add on to say that if you want a special dot product function, you can write one yourself:

```
dot <- function(x, y){   # x and y can be vectors or matrices
    result <- t(x)%*%y   # %*% is the matrix multiplication operator
    print(result)        # t(x) denotes the transpose of x
}
```

Or, as @user3503711 says in his answer, you can just use the dot() function from the geometry library.

Comment: you probably want to return result instead of printing.